# Difference in Arduino pin distance

Tags: arduino-uno, hardware

I have an Arduino Uno rev 3. Today i tried to mount a breadboard as a shield for my Arduino on top of it. I plugged in the pin headers i bought and was surprised that the breadboard won't fit. As you can see in the picture below the distance between Vin and A0 is exactly the size of a pin, but the distance between pin 7 and 8 is less than that and so the breadboard won't fit on this side. What's the reasoning behind this (in my eyes) bad design ?[image: Arduino Uno rev3 with pin header]

Comment: It is a mistake that became a feature for polarizing the shields: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=117441.0

Comment: Thank you. If that wouldn't be so sad it would be a joke...

Comment: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,22737.0.html is the older discussion, with pics of early prototype boards.

Comment: Arguably, if shields could be plugged in either way around (and the wrong way damaging the Arduino and/or the shield) then **that** could be called bad design.

Comment: @NickGammon  That's the *feature* part.    Maybe a better way to key a protoboard/shield would be to block a pin or two.  I think I remember seeing a red plastic plug used to block/key a in the socket on a IDE disk drive connector.

Comment: That is probably a better idea. Ah well, it's like the old joke: "There's no reason for it, it's just always been done that way!"

Answer (score 2):

It is a mistake that became a feature for polarizing the shields: forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=117441.0

In an [2008 discussion](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=22737.msg171839#msg171839) Massimo says:

> "I made that mistake, when I made the first arduino board."

at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=22737.msg171839#msg171839 
with: [image]